# Remove rows using text mining rule into one column

Tags: r

My experimental data has a format like this:

```
df  <-data.frame(product_path = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle", "https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2", "https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane", "https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle3"), var1 = c(1,1,1,0), commereceurl = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/","https://mycommerece.com/product/","https://mycommerece.com/product2/","https://www.test.com"), var2 = c(1,0,0,1))
    > df
                                         product_path var1                      commereceurl var2
    1    https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle    1  https://mycommerece.com/product/    1
    2   https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2    1  https://mycommerece.com/product/    0
    3 https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane    1 https://mycommerece.com/product2/    0
    4   https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle3    0              https://www.test.com    1
```

using the data from the column commereceurl I would like to remove rows which the value in the specific rows doesn't start with this "https://mycommerece.com"

Example of the output

```
df  <-data.frame(product_path = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle", "https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2", "https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane"), var1 = c(1,1,1), commereceurl = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/","https://mycommerece.com/product/","https://mycommerece.com/product2/"), var2 = c(1,0,0))
```

How is it possible to implement this rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify the rows you want with `grep`

```
KEEP = grep("^https://mycommerece.com", df$commereceurl)
df = df[KEEP,]
```